# How can I pass a filename String to another Class so that it creates a File object in that class?

Tags: java, file

I have a file object created in a class called ReadFiles.

```
public class ReadFiles {
    File file = new File("google.csv");
}
```

When entered as above with a set "google.csv" the File creation works.

What I want to do is pass a String filename from another class StockBuySell such that it creates the File in ReadFiles is created based on the String filename. Here is what I tried:

```
public class ReadFiles {

    String filename;

    public ReadFiles(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    File file = new File(filename);
}
```

In the other class in the same package:

```
public class StockBuySell {
    ReadFiles googleData = new ReadFiles("google.csv");
}
```

I am given a NullPointerException. I believe that is because the file is not created by my method. What can I do? Thank you for your help.

Edit: I realized I was running into errors because of other methods related to reading the files. I ended up using hata's method to create a File. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is what you want to achieve like this?:

```
public class ReadFiles {

    File file;
    
    public ReadFiles(String filename) {
        file = new File(filename);
    }
}
```

The reason for your NullPointerException should be the field `File file = new File(filename);`. The `filename` is initially null before the Constructor method is called.

Comment: I tried that just now and it didn't work. Sorry if I'm being confusing. What I wanted was to pass different file names from StockBuySell to ReadFiles so that a File Object is created in ReadFiles. I still don't understand how object-orienting programming in Java works. Thank you for your response.

Comment: This ended up working for me. I was using the ReadingFiles object the wrong way in the other class. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The order of initialization is a bit wonky; first all 'instance initializers' run (and expressions assigned to fields are part of this), and only then the constructor runs. Thus:

```
public class ReadFiles {
    private final String filename;
    private final File file;

    public ReadFiles(String name) {
         this.filename = filename;
         this.file = new File(filename); // put it here.
    }
}
```

There's all sorts of problems with this code, though. It's using old API, and it's got improper naming. (This code is reading 1 file, and yet is named 'ReadFiles'. Also, classes should not be named with a verb, it should describe what it represents, not what it does. It also has an additional, mostly useless field.

Fixing all that:

```
public class CsvReader {
    private final Path file;

    public CsvReader(String path) {
        this.file = Paths.get(path);
    }

    public CsvReader(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

and then we run into yet another problem: reading csvs sounds simple but it isn't. Use a library such as [OpenCSV](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/#opencsv---read-and-parse-csv-file).

Comment: Thank you for the information! I've already read the data in with more complicated methods but I'll keep this in mind.